# Spring Kafka - Delayed messages consumption

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using **spring-kafka 2.9.12** and I'd like to **consume messages** from a topic **after a certain period of time** after the message sending. To do this, **I found two ways**.

**The first approach** is as follows, and I believe it's the more conventional approach:

```java
private final TestProcessor testProcessor;
private final TaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
private MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer;

@KafkaListener(...)
public void listener(ConsumerRecord<String, TestMessage> message) throws ProcessException {
    long waitUntil = message.timestamp() + 20_000L;
    if(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() < waitUntil) {
        TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(message.topic(), message.partition());
        listenerContainer.pausePartition(topicPartition);
        scheduler.schedule(() -> listenerContainer.resumePartition(topicPartition), Instant.ofEpochMilli(waitUntil));
        throw new KafkaBackoffException(
                "Wait until: %s".formatted(waitUntil),
                topicPartition,
                TopicEnum.TEST.name(),
                waitUntil);
    } else {
        testProcessor.process(message.value());
    }
}
```

**The second approach** is easier but messier. I use the retry topic backoff mechanism basically simply by sending a message with the `DEFAULT_HEADER_BACKOFF_TIMESTAMP` header, as follows:

```java
private ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> send2() {
        return kt.send(new ProducerRecord<>(
                "test",
                null,
                UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                new TestMessage(random.nextLong(1000L)),
                List.of(new RecordHeader(DEFAULT_HEADER_BACKOFF_TIMESTAMP, BigInteger.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + 20_000).toByteArray()))));
    }
```

I tested them and both approaches seem to work.

However, I have some concerns about potential pitfalls (especially for the second approach).
I'm just afraid of doing something wrong so am I missing something? Are both approaches correct? Which one do you prefer?

Any advice? Sorry for the somewhat vague question.

Answer (score 1):

The approach with the `MessageListenerContainer.pause()` and eventually resume is the right way to achieve your goal. However I wouldn't do that in the `@KafkaListener` method since it is triggered exactly when record is consumed from the topic. Consider to move your `pause()/resume()`  logic into some other management component.